# Use of a Dialog box on Material Design

Tags: website-design

I'm designing this web app., but I can't reveal its name or main function, so let's see how this can be explained...

In this app., there's a level of user that has the ability to add or remove team members (employees). For this user to do that, I thought I'd make it easy and have the user just press the "+" button and fill in a little form, but to make it even more seamless, let's make that a dialog box.

**Question**: Is it normal for a user to write stuff in a dialog box, or are those typically only for information displays such as alerts, etc.?

Below, you can enter the link to the dialog section on material design and a screenshot of how this dialog/form is going to look (I need to add the lines below every line like any other form, but I just stopped after this question pop right into my mind).

[image]

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#

Comment: Is this meant to be used from the desktop or mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

Cristobal, the Behavior section of the material design you referred to, provides a clear explanation of when to use dialogues:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-behavior

The dialog types listed here don’t seem to refer to the one you are considering, since it requires more than just (1) becoming aware of urgent information, (2) a simple selection or (3) confirming a choice.
Allowing the user to simply and quickly select a button to either deleting a user (and use a modal alert to confirm this non-reversible action) or providing information to add a new user (and use a modal alert for error messages and such) may be a more appropriate user experience, especially since the Material guidelines stress that “Dialogs should avoid: Opening dialogs from within a dialog.”

Comment: As a second thought, you may not need additional modals to communicate input errors, rather this:
https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/errors.html#errors-user-input-errors